# Change the title name of an A tag based on a H1 title

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to change the name of an A tag title based on a H1 title

```
<a href="/servicing/2016-03-13-18-38-56" title="Assets"></a>

<h1 title="Unit"></h1>
```

So when the H1 title changes it changes the title of the A tag

this is the text box code

```
<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="asset_string" id="asset_string" size="40" maxlength="255" value="unit">
```

this is the asset_string PHP function

```
function getAssetWord() {
    $settings = AssetsController::loadSettings();
    if (!$settings->asset_string) {
        $settings->asset_string = JText::_('ASSETS_ASSET');
    }
    return $settings->asset_string;
}

function getAssetsWord() {
    return AssetsController::getAssetWord() . 's';
}
```

i havent tried anything yet, as i am unsure what to use

Comment: how H1 title change ?

Comment: its changed manually,

Comment: there is a text box, when a title is added to the text box, it changes the H1 tag

Comment: you should include the code so far, you have done. and the code which binds h1 title from textbox

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear on how you **want** to achieve this.. but following through the comments and you stating this:

> *there is a text box, when a title is added to the text box, it changes the H1 tag*

I assume this is what you're talking about:

---

**HTML:**

```
<h1 title="Test Header>
    I am H1 Element
</h1>

<div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" id="Link" title="Test Link">I am a Link</a>
</div>


<div>
  <input type="text" id="TextInput" />
</div>
```

---

**JS/jQuery:**

```
$("#TextInput").on("input",function(){
    $("h1").attr("title",$("#TextInput").val());
    $("#Link").attr("title",$("#TextInput").val());
});
```

---

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vrhn629/2/).  Basically whatever is entered into the textbox, it will change the `title` attribute of both the `h1` and `a` elements.

Let me know if this helps or if anything needs to be tailored.

Comment: hi thanks for the help, there is not button click, the `title` of the A tag just needs to change when the `H1` title is changed, there is a text box which a user can add a word, which then changes the title of the `H1` tag, when the `H1` tag changes the `A tag title` needs to change, so no on click event

Comment: @user2513528 updated my answer to not include a button click.. rather when the input changes within the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are looking for.

```js
$('#changeTitle').change(function(){
  $('h1, a').attr('title', $(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/servicing/2016-03-13-18-38-56" title="Assets">A</a>

<h1 title="Unit">H1</h1>

<input type="text" id="changeTitle"/>
```

Comment: I don't think, if in question it mentioned that on click event, he wants to  change the title ?